# How to specify array ([]) type in Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

Hi I am trying to autogenerate a class using swagger plugin. One property of this class has to be array, but when I write type: "array" always create a List.

This is part of my "yml" file:

```
...
probabilities:
        type: "array"
        items:
          type: "number"
          format: "double"
          minimum: 0
          maximum: 1
        description:
          "Vector with probabilities"
        example: [ 0.5, 0.3, 0.1 ]
...
```

And this is the property that create:

```
...
 @JsonProperty("probabilities")
 @SerializedName("probabilities")
 private List<Double> probabilities = new ArrayList<Double>();
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, an array has a fixed length. This is different from OpenAPI and JavaScript specifications, where an array can have variable length at runtime. The variable-length equivalent in Java is the `List`.

The [implementation of swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/3577960243cb602dbb3f15981502a1e8c1f0c9f6/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java#L422) for Java converts an `array` into a `java.util.List`